# Is it possible to use list RSS to display data external?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, rss

There is list that have RSS activated, is it possible to display the data external?

They want it as 2.x standard format:

Here is an example:

```
<item> <title>Title of an item</title> <link>http://example.com/item/123</link> <guid>http://example.com/item/123</guid> <pubDate>Mon, 12 Sep 2005 18:37:00 GMT</pubDate> <description>[CDATA[ This is the description. ]]</description> </item>
```

and then display it on external page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on Anonymous access for this list, once enabled you will be able to consume the feed externally.

You can find steps to turn on Anonymous access [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Enable-anonymous-access-3647cdd5-1ab8-48cf-b4ee-d1b652bbabdd) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2852733/how-to-enable-anonymous-authentication-on-sharepoint).

[image]

Comment: Okey but regarding the format of the rss feed how Do i get it in the format I did example in the question?

Comment: The RSS feed version for SP 2013 is 2.0. You will get the feed in the format as in my answer above (updated)